# C++ SFML Joystick Input

Tags: c++, sfml, joystick

I'm working on a college pair-programming project using SFML & C++ to make a two-player 2D Game.

---

**TL;DR:**

*How can I make `Xbox360Controller` instance be accessible from anywhere in the game? [Do keep in mind, if you recommend a `Singleton Pattern` that there will be two controllers connected].*

---

We have an engine written from our classes in college, we made things such as `ResourceManager`, `SceneGraph`, `CommandQueue`, `StateStack`, `Input Action bindings`, etc.

The engines functionality is separated into `update()`, `draw()`, `handleEvent()` & a separate `handleRealtimeInput()` in `Player.cpp`.

I have written and reworked a `Xbox360Controller` class in my [Github](https://github.com/Alex-Jay/k-arnage_2d_sfml_game/blob/feature/joystick/GD4GameWorld/include/Structural/Xbox360Controller.hpp) (ignore the `static GetController()` method for the time-being).

Initially, the original class from **dustinfreeman's** [GitHub](https://github.com/dustinfreeman/sfml-controller/blob/master/Xbox360Controller.h) used a `Singleton` pattern but we need to allow for 2 controllers being connected.

I'm not sure if I should still use Singleton type of class or should I make an instance of a `Xbox360Controller` for a specific player.

Currently, I am attempting to use the second implementation but in my `Application.cpp` when I create an instance in the constructor, I would like the entire application to access the controller events such as shown below:

```
Application::Application()
    :mWindow(sf::VideoMode(1024, 768), "Audio", sf::Style::Close)
    , mTextures()
    , mFonts()
    , mPlayer()
    , mMusic()
    , mSounds()
    , mStateStack(State::Context(mWindow, mTextures, mFonts, mPlayer, mMusic, mSounds))
    , mStatisticsText()
    , mStatisticsUpdateTime()
    , mStatisticsNumFrames(0)
{
    mWindow.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false);

    mFonts.load(FontIDs::Main, "Media/Sansation.ttf");

    mTextures.load(TextureIDs::TitleScreen, "Media/Textures/TitleScreen.png");
    mTextures.load(TextureIDs::Buttons, "Media/Textures/Buttons.png");

    registerStates();
    mStateStack.pushState(StateIDs::Title);

    // This line creates an instance for a controller if a controller is connected
    if (sf::Joystick::Count > 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Joystick Connected." << std::endl;
        // This instance should be available everywhere
        Xbox360Controller controller(0);
    }
}

// This runs in the game-loop
void Application::processInput()
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (mWindow.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (sf::Joystick::isConnected(0))
        {
            // Do something [For testing], eventually, pass the event into StateStack
        }

        mStateStack.handleEvent(event);

        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
        {
            mWindow.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How many controllers are allowed? Can you have 2 singletons eg controller1 and controller2? I've never designed an engine so I'm not sure if that's viable.

Comment: @BradyDean, We're hoping to have `up to 2 controllers` for now but in our next semester, we're hoping to add the support for 4 controllers for extra marks (but that's not important now). Our project is due `14th of February, 2019` so I'm trying to do things neat and quick.

Comment: Maybe have an singleton array and abstract it away in an interface. If I had any better idea I'd post an answer but those are just my initial thoughts.

Comment: @BradyDean do you mean an array of `Xbox360Controller` pointers?

Comment: I was thinking an array of controllers. You would need a mechanism to specify which ones are in use but then you could have a method return an iterator to the active ones and poll them etc.

Comment: @BradyDean I'll look into doing that. We do something similar with `ResourceManager` so I'll try to outsource code from there. If all else fails, I'll try something else.

Comment: You should be able to just return a `std::vector<Xbox360Controller>` from your static method. Or wrap the controller is `std::shared_ptr` if you need to share the same instances of controller in different places. Personally I wouldn't use `Singleton` at all, I would just pass the controller down to wherever it's needed.

Comment: @super Would it make sense for me to have a vector of controllers in my `Context struct`? [Github Code Highlight](https://github.com/Alex-Jay/k-arnage_2d_sfml_game/blob/ad4ce613d795c17ae8112ffb0d171a779afed7a8/GD4GameWorld/include/State/State.hpp#L26-L35). Context allows to access data between states. Currently I have an `Xbox360Controller* controller` private member variable in my `Player.hpp`